# Cannot access my ASP pages on LAN

Tags: windows-7, ip, iis, asp

I can access my `asp pages` on my PC using "localhost". But, I cannot access the files over the LAN using the ip-address.

It's the same case on my pc. When I enter the ip-address (of my PC) I do not get the pages.

Can any one help? **I want to be able to access my `asp pages` via IP-address**. I'm on Windows 7

Comment: How are you hosting the ASP file?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure Windows firewall allows connection through port 80.

Temporarily turn it off and see if it is accessible.

Comment: Hi ! I tried that too. Turned off windows firewall. Problem still the same.